# photorec couldn't recover last saved file

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

Yesterday I deleted by mistake the content of current directory which had many c programs. Later I successfully recovered all the files **(using command photorec)** with one issue.

The issue is:
for 1 file I saw that the last saved matter wasn't recovered. I explain what I mean: I wrote a file, saved then edited again saved and edited.... For that file I see that many files are present in the recovered files. In 1 recovered file 5 lines of code (for that file) is present and in other 30 lines. But the matter that was present in the file when I last saved it couldn't be recovered. So what I mean is that intermediate matters are recovered of that file but the last saved one wasn't present in the recovered files. Does one has any idea why so!! Because it seems if previous matters are recovered then last saved should obviously be present in the recovered files.

This Q is a result of [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/ubuntu-how-to-recover-files-i-deleted-now-by-running-rm).

Comment: last sentence - why is this obvious?

Comment: Doesn't it seem obvious. To me it seemed so. I created a file wrote something saved again, edited again and saved. That way did this many times. So, earlier matter overwritten with new. So, doesn't it seem that if one can retrieve older matter, latest ones should be more easy (because its what the file finally contained overwriting the previous ones). An analogy to our memory: one reads today something, tomorrow something new and so on for 10 days. So, after 10 days what latest he read should be in his memory even if he forgets what he read on 1st day.

Comment: yes, but think about this: if the file's overwritten when a newer version is saved, how could you have possibly retrieved the old version?

Comment: @strugee yes the answer to your question can focus light on what I want to know. This technical knowledge (of your Q) is what I wish you or someone to reply.