# How can I recover a deleted Data Base file from Oracle Enterprise Linux?

Tags: data-recovery

How Can I recover a deleted Data Base file from Oracle Linux ..

file system type is ext4.

It is really crucial to bring up the db..

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I tried the below links but could not succeed.

[Unix/Linux undelete/recover deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files)

[How to recover files I deleted now by running rm *?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/how-to-recover-files-i-deleted-now-by-running-rm)

Comment: Restore from your last backup and then recover to point-in-time by using the redo logs.

Comment: I don't have backup and DB is in no archive log mode

Comment: Good luck restoring the database. Unfortunately the best thing to revert `rm` is backup. There is a reason why backup is so advised.

Comment: I am sorry for you, but you have almost no chances to restore it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly stop using the drive because any changes to the file system will make it harder to recover.

Secondly take a copy of the entire drive using dd or other tools to copy the raw drive to a clean disk.

Next you will need to look at various ext3/4 undeletion tools, always working with the cloned drive never the original. The tools that I know of are:

- ext4magic: http://ext4magic.sourceforge.net/ext4magic_en.html
- ext3grep: http://code.google.com/p/ext3grep/
- extundelete: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Next options are:

- Send the drive off for data recovery
- Look at file carving tools such as photoreq (from the testdisk package)
- Accept the loss of data and rebuild with backups as part of the planning process

Comment: This process has a low probability of success along with a lot of frustrating effort.

Comment: Agreed, I was putting forward the steps I would take in this case